# Android studio logcat json pretty print trims whitespaces

Tags: android, json, android-studio, logcat, pretty-print

there is a logged bug with Android Studio about trimming whitespaces in LogCat. Which means that if you want to pretty print JSON, you are not able to.
Code

```
new JSONObject(json).toString(4);
```

simply won't work.

Please check my answer if you need this to be working. I came up with super simple solution using GSON and no break space character.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Until the bug is fixed you can use this code for pretty printing in logcat:

```
public static String prettyJson(String body) {
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
      return body;
   }
   try {
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
      StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
      JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter);
      jsonWriter.setIndent("\u00A0\u00A0");
      JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(body);
      gson.toJson(jsonElement, jsonWriter);
      return stringWriter.toString();
   } catch (JsonParseException e) {
      return body;
   }
}
```

What is does is that it simply uses no break space for indenting which is not considered a whitespace.